# How can I write css for media print using JavaScript, due to special css for ie8 compatibility mode?

Tags: javascript, css, printing, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

I am setting up some css for @media print and I had to make use of IE conditionals to get it cross-browser compatible.  Looking here and elsewhere, it seems there's no IE conditionals that detect IE 8 compatibility mode.  The only way to do so is make use of meta tags or JavaScript, correct?

I know how to detect compatibility mode in JavaScript.  My question is how do I write one particular line of css for @media print using JavaScript.  If i have to, I'll settle for linking to a separate stylesheet.  But I managed to get my current print media stylesheet cross-browser compatible, with the notable exception of ie 8 compatibility mode.  If I can just add what I need in JavaScript, instead of creating a separate stylesheet for IE 8 compatibility mode, that would be great.  Either way, I would like to know how I can add @media print css for IE 8 compatibility mode using Javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just to add inline `style` tag:

```
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = "@media print { h1 {color: gray;} } /* just an example */";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Can you give me an example of how to formulate the innerHMTL?  Is it something like "<@media print { #div_test { display:none; } }";

Comment: I would just add that it should be added to the head, not to the body.  But I think that should do it; not tested on all browsers, though.  Thank you.

Comment: The code of innerHTML depends on what do you want to have in your print @media query

Comment: I added an example into the innerHTML. Just to make the format clear